# How to change datatables display string at bottom

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables plugin . 
While using it shows - "Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries", something like this at bottom . 
I want to change this . Can anyone helps me how to change this?

Comment: So what do you want to change? Position? Text? No message at all?

Comment: Its displaying "Filtered results 6 of 10 entries", during table init.I want that to be displayed as "showing 1 to 6 of 10 entries"...something like that. I am first drawing empty table and then adding content to it from ajax call (on clicking a button ).

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same language mod @Jef gave in his answer?

Comment: Jef's answer worked . @mainguy....Thanks for your concern....

Comment: Then it would be fair to mark it as answered so others with the same issue may see it and to give @Jef his earned reps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the sInfo and sInfoEmpty strings like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
      "oLanguage": {
         "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
         "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries"
      }
   } );
} );
```

See media/js/jquery.dataTables.js, lines 9272-9309 in the current version (DataTables-1.9.4)

Comment: I am using spring MVC . In the response I am returning, it contains iTotalRecords field,which I am not setting anywhere . It's getting set automatically .Also at bottom it's showing "Filtered 6 results of 10 results",which I thought might be due to iTotalRecords/iTotalDisplayRecords . I want that string to be "Showing 0 to 6 of 10 entries".

Comment: Moreover, I found that iTotalRecords/iTotalDisplayRecords might be the problem from http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1165/why-i-got-filtered-from-x-total-entries-in-the-footer/p1

Comment: Post an example of the code you are using to create the DataTable.

Comment: that worked ..............thats what I am expecting exactly..........thanks a lot